# How to call stored procedure using sails-sqlserver?

Tags: sails.js

I am new to sails. I want to call stored procedure using sails-sqlserver adapter. Procedure returns result set using a query which join multiple table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to call procedure. I am connecting to SQL server database. sails doesn't provide default adapter to connect to SQL Server. I have used sails-sqlserver adapter for this.

few points which I observed.

1. To call a procedure or query we need a model.
2. You don't need to have table with model name in database. You also don't need 
   to specify attributes in model file.
3. When I used dash "-" in my model name it was not working. example "Report-data"
4. I used underscore in my model name and it worked. example "Report_data"

To generate controller and model I used below command:

```js
sails generate api Report_data
```

Above command will create controller file and model file.

5. You need to add route in route.js file. example this is what I did

```js
'/api/Report_data':{
controller:'Report_dataController',
action: 'getReport'
}
```

6. You need to write action inside controller "Report_data". Below is my controller code

```js
module.exports = {
 'getReport':function(req,res){
        Report_data.query('get_sample_report',function(err,resultSet){
            if(err){
                res.json(err);
            }
            else{
                res.ok(resultSet);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

That's it. Lift sails and call api in browser:
http://localhost:1337/api/Report_data

Note: I had disabled all blueprint/waterline default routes in blueprint.js file

```js
//blueprint.js
action:false,
rest:false,
shortcuts:false
```

Also if your sql server connection is not working please make sure that you don't provide port in host name. example my host name for sql server which I used in sql server management studio is "servername.domainname.com/zone1,1433".

When I used same host name in connection.js file. it didn't work. I removed "zone1,1433" from connection.js file (host property) and connection worked.